# Recode based on TRUE or FALSE in another variable

Tags: r

I'm calculating a new variable based on the TRUE/FALSE status of another:

```
value<-c(2, 4, 5, 8, 2, 3, 1)
tf<-c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
df<-data.frame(value, tf)
```

The following code does what I need (halves 'value' if 'tf' is TRUE)...

```
df$newVals[which(df$tf)]<-df$value[which(df$tf)]/2
df$newVals[which(!df$tf)]<-df$value[which(!df$tf)]
```

...but it feels too complicated.  Is there a simpler approach?

Thanks

Comment: You could start by eliminating the redundant which calls...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a very simple solution without `ifelse`:

```
df$newVals <- with(df, value / (tf + 1))
```

*How it works?*

If boolean values (like `tf`) are used with mathematical operators, they are cast into numeric values (`FALSE` is transformed to `0` and `TRUE` is transformed to `1`). Hence the command `tf + 1` creates a numeric vector of `1`s and `2`s. The values in `value` are divided by the values in this new vector. A division by one does not change the original values.

Comment: To be slicker this should be `df <- within(df, newVals <- value / (tf + 1))` or `df <- transform(df, newVals = value / (tf = 1))`. No point using `with()` only to use `$` on the LHS of `<-`.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich I added an explanation to the answer.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein - that's a great answer and the explantation really helped.  Thank you

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with `ifelse`:

```
value<-c(2, 4, 5, 8, 2, 3, 1)
tf<-c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
df<-data.frame(value, tf)

df$newVals <- with(df, ifelse(tf, value/2, value))
```

Comment: Personally, I'd go with this. Sven's answer is very smart but it does not read as well as a good old `ifelse`.

Comment: @SachaEpskamp this is the sort of thing I knew was possible, but couldn't quite get to.  Accepted Sven's answer but this is a good one too.  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Using `ifelse` and `transform` will do it for you

```
 transform(df, newVals=ifelse(tf, value/2,value))
      value    tf newVals
    1     2  TRUE     1.0
    2     4 FALSE     4.0
    3     5 FALSE     5.0
    4     8 FALSE     8.0
    5     2  TRUE     1.0
    6     3 FALSE     3.0
    7     1  TRUE     0.5
```

Comment: yes, but you don't even need the `df$` bits in the expression [and you're better off without them])

Comment: @Jilber - I hadn't seen transform before, useful function to know about.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different tack; just update the values that need to change rather than all the values and select from them using `ifelse()`. E.g.

```
value<-c(2, 4, 5, 8, 2, 3, 1)
tf<-c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
df<-data.frame(value, tf)

df <- transform(df, newVals = value) ## task a copy of `value`
df[df$tf, "newVals"] <- df[df$tf, "value"] / 2 ## update only ones we want
df
```

Giving

```
> df
  value    tf newVals
1     2  TRUE     1.0
2     4 FALSE     4.0
3     5 FALSE     5.0
4     8 FALSE     8.0
5     2  TRUE     1.0
6     3 FALSE     3.0
7     1  TRUE     0.5
```

You could break this down a bit if you don't like all the indexing - just create `ind` which contains the indexes of the rows where `tf` is `TRUE`:

```
df <- transform(df, newVals = value)
ind <- with(df, which(tf))
df[ind, "newVals"] <- df[ind, "value"] / 2
df

> df
  value    tf newVals
1     2  TRUE     1.0
2     4 FALSE     4.0
3     5 FALSE     5.0
4     8 FALSE     8.0
5     2  TRUE     1.0
6     3 FALSE     3.0
7     1  TRUE     0.5
```

Comment: @GavinSimspson, this is great, thank you.  Make a copy first, then change the values - so obvious when you see it.